# How to examine performance counters in c#?

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter

I have some performance issues in my application.

I have read on msdn that it would be a good idea to look at the performance counter that tells about % Time in GC.

See this link from msdn: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764(v=vs.110).aspx#IsGC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#IsGC)

But I cant seem to find a way to view this performance counter.

How would i do that?

Comment: Programmatically or via GUI? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/11/04/how-to-use-perfmon-in-windows-7.aspx http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx

Comment: I need any solution(GUI or programmatically) that can use performance counters to display % time in GC. The GUI example you link to seems good. I'll take a look at that. Thx.

Comment: If your program feels laggy, then you could also use profilers to detect the time consuming functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counter % Time in GC is under .Net CLR Memory , press add counter in perfmon and you will see this window

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for the Time in GC counter.